# Remove function in React with .filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

While building a Todo app, I want to filter out an object out of my array with a remove function. So far I got this.

```
deleteTask(task) {

    let taskList = this.state.tasks;

    var newTask = taskList.filter(function(_task) { return _task != task})

    this.setState({ 
        tasks: newTask
    });

}
```

Only problem is, the function returns the whole array while using the function. 
So the Task argument that should return just an object out of my array returns the whole array instead while in my newTask var.

How can I bind or make this function work?

The array which I am wanting to remove an object from is not located in the same Component, dont know if that matters. But for extra info.

Comment: Please add what you are getting inside both task and use arrow functions please =>

Comment: what is the structure of the `state.tasks` and `task` parameter?

Comment: You'll have to use some unique identifier of the task. Like this: `var newTask = taskList.filter(t => t.id != task.id)`. You might also want to read this: [*Equality comparisons and sameness*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let's see why `_task != task` doesn't work as you need. Try this:

```js
const a = { x: 10, y: 'hello' };
const b = { x: 10, y: 'hello' };
console.log(
  a==b,
  a===b,
  Object.is(a,b)
);
```

Suprising, eh? Read [this](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html) for more details.

Anyway, you should refactor your code to include an `id` property in your tasks, so that you can compare two tasks with their ids - no need to worry about weird implementations of object comparisons in JavaScript!

This should then work:

```
deleteTask(taskId) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    tasks: prevState.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== taskId)
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Equality operator in javascript compares the references of the object. So even if both object have same value, since they point to different instances, == will always return false. So as I see you have two options:

1. Refactor your code to include a id part and which that to compare two tasks.
2. Use some library like lodash or underscore for deep comparison

Comment: Also thanks for the tip. I'll start using the libraries once I understand JS a bit more